# Turn ordered pairs into unordered pairs in a data frame with dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a data frame that looks like this:

```
library(dplyr)
df <- data_frame(doc.x = c("a", "b", "c", "d"),
                 doc.y = c("b", "a", "d", "c"))
```

So that `df` is:

```
Source: local data frame [4 x 2]

  doc.x doc.y
  (chr) (chr)
1     a     b
2     b     a
3     c     d
4     d     c
```

This is a list of ordered pairs, `a` to `d` but also `d` to `a`, and so on. What is a dplyr-like way to return only a list of unordered pairs in this data frame? I.e.

```
  doc.x doc.y
  (chr) (chr)
1     a     b
2     c     d
```

Comment: The first code block does not match the second and third.

Comment: @Backlin: Thanks, I've fixed it.

Comment: @Jaap: I think it might need to be `df %>% arrange(doc.x) %>% slice(1:(nrow(df)/2))` to be a general solution, but that should work.

Comment: You didn't say that it had to be ordered by `doc.x`, neither did you say that you needed the top half. If you need both, than that is indeed a general solution. Please specify such requirements in the future. Most of us do not have the capacity of mindreading ;-)

Comment: Thanks for correcting, but isn't the third code block incorrect now? If you want the *unordered* pairs then the expected output should not contain both (a,b) and (b,a), but rather (a,b) and (c,d), like @Chris's solution.

Comment: @Jaap: It doesn't have to be ordered by `doc.x`, but the pairs might not already ordered as in the example above. Since I hadn't considered a solution using `slice()` that problem hadn't occurred to me.

Comment: @Backlin, yes, my mistake. Fixed now.

Comment: Does every pair appear twice, once each way? If so... `df %>% filter(doc.x > doc.y)`

Comment: @Frank, because of the way the data frame was created, yes, each pair should appear twice.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use `pmin` and `pmax` to sort the pairs alphabetically, i.e. turn (b,a) into (a,b) and then filter away all the duplicates.

```
df %>%
    mutate(dx = pmin(doc.x, doc.y), dy = pmax(doc.x, doc.y)) %>%
    distinct(dx, dy) %>%
    select(-dx, -dy)
```

```
  doc.x doc.y
  (chr) (chr)
1     a     b
2     c     d
```

Comment: `df %>% distinct(dn = pmin(doc.x,doc.y), up = pmax(doc.x,doc.y)) %>% select(-up,-dn)` since `distinct` is there for deduping.

Comment: Slick - I like how you used `pmin` and `pmax`

Answer (score 2):

Alternate way using `data.table`:

```
df <- data.frame(doc.x = c("a", "b", "c", "d"),
                 doc.y = c("b", "a", "d", "c"), stringsAsFactors = F)


library(data.table)
setDT(df)
df[, row := 1:nrow(df)]
df <- df[, list(Left = max(doc.x,doc.y),Right = min(doc.x,doc.y)), by = row]
df <- df[, list(Left,Right)]
unique(df)
   Left Right
1:    b     a
2:    d     c
```

Comment: You should use `row := 1:nrow(df)`, because `length(df)` will get you the number of columns rather than rows.

Comment: @akrun he's looking for unordered pairs, so `b a` is equivalent to `a b`

Answer (score 1):

Using `dplyr`

```
# make character columns into factors
df <- as.data.frame(unclass(df))
df$x.lvl <- levels(df$doc.x)
df$y.lvl <- levels(df$doc.y)

# find unique pairs
res <- df %>% 
  group_by(doc.x) %>%
  transform(x.lvl = order(doc.x), 
    y.lvl = order(doc.y)) %>%
  transform(pair = ifelse(x.lvl < y.lvl, 
        paste(doc.x, doc.y, sep=","), paste(doc.y, doc.x, sep=","))) %>%  
  .$pair %>%
  unique
```

Unique pairs

```
res
[1] a,b c,d
Levels: a,b c,d
```

**Edit**

Inspired by Backlin's solution, in base R

```
unique(with(df, paste(pmin(doc.x, doc.y), pmax(doc.x, doc.y), sep=","))
[1] "a,b" "c,d"
```

Or to store in a data.frame

```
unique(with(df, data.frame(lvl1=pmin(doc.x, doc.y), lvl2=pmax(doc.x, doc.y))))

  lvl1 lvl2
1    a    b
3    c    d
```